# Ionic 3.10.3 ERROR when i update

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I update ionic 3.10.2 to 3.10.3 and i got this when i try build or something.

```
geen$ ionic serve
[INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 
       --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 - Ctrl+C to cancel
[15:17:28]  watch started ... 
[15:17:28]  build dev started ... 
[15:17:28]  clean started ... 
[15:17:28]  clean finished in 1 ms 
[15:17:28]  copy started ... 
[15:17:28]  transpile started ... 
[15:17:30]  transpile finished in 1.99 s 
[15:17:30]  preprocess started ... 
[15:17:30]  deeplinks started ... 
[15:17:30]  deeplinks finished in 22 ms 
[15:17:30]  preprocess finished in 22 ms 
[15:17:30]  webpack started ... 
[15:17:30]  copy finished in 2.09 s
```

If i type `ionic serve` or `ionic cordova build android` or `ionic cordova run android -c -l` to debug in my phone I get the same print.

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: I found the error and post the answer. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. When you have in a component more than one class in the same .ts file ionic don't print the error but at the same time doesn't compile.